# Java Spring REST all catch sub-urls

Tags: java, rest, url

Does someone know a good solution to catch sub URLs with Java Spring REST?

For example, I have urls:

http://example.com/hauses/toll/country/usa?...

http://example.com/hauses/small/country/germany?...

http://example.com/hauses/underground/country/norway?...

...

Solution for one of them will be something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hauses/underground/country")
public class ProxyController {

    @GetMapping("/norway")
    public String readSalesOrder(HttpServletRequest request) {
          some code
    }
}
```

But I need to catch everything that after "/hauses". Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hauses/*")
```

Does someone know solution for this?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestMapping("/hauses/**")` may help

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex